# Is it possible to edit existing Kubernetes resources using Terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to deploy a Kubernetes cluster using Terraform. In order to install nginx on my cluster, I wrote this inside my .tf file:

```
resource "helm_release" "ingress" {
    name      = "ingress"
    chart     = "stable/nginx-ingress"
     namespace = "kube-system"

    set {
        name = "controller.replicaCount"
        value = "1"
    }
    depends_on = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s]
}
```

Everything works fine, nginx gets deployed, but I want to mount a configmap on the deployment. I'm pretty sure I can't do that before the nginx deployment gets created by Terraform, so I am wondering if I can  do it after. The configmap is also created with Terraform:

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "nginx" {
  metadata {
    name = "my-name"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
  data = {
    "my-field" = "${file("${path.module}/C:/my_configmap.yaml")}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Since Terraform is interacting with your Nginx deployment on Kubernetes through Helm, you would probably need to continue interacting with Helm inside Terraform, unless you wanted to switch to direct interaction.

Comment: Didn't think of that. I think it could work. Thanks!

Comment: @MattSchuchard I looked into it and nginx does not have an option for `volumes` and `volumeMounts`. [Link](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/#configuration)

Comment: You would need to add it into the Helm chart locally, or submit a PR.